# A function that should return a struct, how can i print this struct in C++?

Tags: function, mbed, lora

I'm using mbed online compiler to write a program and upload it to a multitech mDot LoRa tranceiver. my program basically is about sending packets of a specific size to the gateway. at the end of my program I want to get some statistics about the communication. so I've been told to use a function called getStats(); that is in one of the header files (mDot.h). all what is mentioned about this function the mDot.h is the following:

```
class mDot { 
    public:
    typedef struct {
                uint32_t Up;
                uint32_t Down;
                uint32_t Joins;
                uint32_t JoinFails;
                uint32_t MissedAcks;
        } mdot_stats;

 // get current statistics
 // Join Attempts, Join Fails, Up Packets, Down Packets, Missed Acks

 mdot_stats getStats();
```

so any ideas please on how can I call this function in my main.cpp and get the values (Up, Down, Joins, JoinFails and MissedAcks) printed in my consle screen.
Really appreciate your help as i really need this..

Noman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
mDot::mdot_stats stats = dot->getStats();
printf("Number of uplink packets %d\n", stats.Up);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If an answer solved your problem, please click the 'Accepted' box next to the answer :-).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have printf available you can simply do:

```
void print(const mdot_stats& stats){
    printf("Join Attempts: %d,\t" stats.Joins);
    printf("Join Fails: %d,\t" stats.JoinFails);
    printf("Up Packets: %d,\t" stats.Up);
    printf("Down Packets: %d,\t" stats.Down);
    printf("Missed Acks: %d,\t" stats.MissedAcks);
}
```

Otherwise, if you are lucky enough to have ostreams in your embedded environment you can always override the << operator.